# Initialize a List<string> with a string

Tags: c#

What is the easiest way to Initialize a List with a string?
Say I have a

```
String a="a"
List<string> b;
```

How could I initialized b with a string "a"?

Answer (score 9):

```
var b = new List<string> {a};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String a = "a";
  List<string> b = new List<string>{a};
```